# How do backslash escapes work with echo -E in  zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I have a script where I need to preserve the `\\` character sequences but the command `echo -E \\` prints `\` when it should be `\\`.  Correct?

Is this a bug in the version of Ubuntu I am using?  I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and I am using zsh version :

```
% zsh --version                         
zsh 4.3.11 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh` you could use

```
echo -E '\\'
```

to print to consecutive backslashes, or if you do not want to use quotes

```
echo -E \\\\
```